# Shiny - disable selection of radio buttons upon selection of a checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to incorperate code in shiny to disable the selection of certain radio buttons upon the selection of a checkbox? For example, upon selection of ID039, selection of ID038 and ID037 would be disabled? For the given example, I need to ensure that if the checkbox option (NA) is selected, the summary table does not compute the minimum score for ID038 and ID037.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse) 
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("united"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("TITLE"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select",
        label = helpText("Select a critera"),
        choices = list("Criteria_1", "Criteria_2"),
        selected = c("NULL")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Criteria", conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id037_crit1",
            label = "Predictions:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          ),
        ),
        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id038_crit1",
            label = "Hypotheses:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          )
        ),
    
# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  calc_min_val <- function(contains) {
    radios_inputid <- str_subset(names(input), contains)
    map_dbl(radios_inputid, ~ as.numeric(input[[.x]])) %>%
      min()
  }
  
  summ <- reactive({
    min_values <- c("crit1$", "crit2$") %>%
      map(calc_min_val)
    
    tibble(
      Lowest_Criteria = c("Specific hypotheses and prediction are provided?", "Predictions regarding the electromagnetic area of 
interest are sufficient?"),
      value = map(min_values, ~.)
    )
  })
  
  output$summary <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(summ())
  })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have a better chance of getting answers if you focus on one problem in each question.

Comment: Thank you. I will break this up into a few questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the radio buttons you can use `shinyjs` package and the following code on the server side.

```
 observeEvent(input$Id039_crit1,{
    if (input$Id039_crit1) {
      shinyjs::disable("Id037_crit1")
      shinyjs::disable("Id038_crit1")
    }else {
      shinyjs::enable("Id037_crit1")
      shinyjs::enable("Id038_crit1")
    }
  })
```